# How to integrate nRF24L01 to esp8266 nodeMCU?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, nrf24l01+

I can't seem to integrate an nRF module to my nodeMCU.
I just want to verify my code but an error message keeps popping up

Below is the sketch:

```
#include <SPI_Class.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define PIN_CE D4
#define PIN_CSN D3
RF24 radio(PIN_CE, PIN_CSN);

struct package{
  int id = 1;
  int location = 1;
  char timeStamp = "date/time"
};

typedef struct package Package;
Package data;

public int data1=data.id;
public int data2=data.location;
public char data3=data.timeStamp;

byte  address[][6] = "00001"

const char* ssid = "Jino";
const char* pass = "myinternet";

char server[] = "cdgresearch.000webhostapp.com";

WiFiClient client;

int led = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {

    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Successfully connected to the network");
  Serial.print("NodeMCU IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  delay(1000);

  radio.begin();
  radio.setChannel(115);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[0]);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(9000);
  sendData();
}

void sendData(){
  Serial.println("Sending Data...");
  delay(1000);
  if (client.connect(server, 80)){
    WiFi.printDiag(Serial);
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
    client.print("GET /tag2.php?");
    client.print("incoming=Id ");
    client.print(data1);
    client.print("&incoming2=Loc");
    client.print(data2);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: cdgresearch.000webhostapp.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    Serial.println();

    while(client.connected()){
      while(client.available()){
        Serial.write(client.read());
       }
      }
    radio.write(&data,sizeof(data));

    Serial.print("\nPackage: ");
    Serial.println(data1);
    Serial.print("Location: ")
    Serial.println(data2)
    Serial.println(data3)
    data1+=1;
    data2+=1;
    delay(1000);

  }

  else{
    Serial.println("Failed to Connect to server...");
    }

  client.stop();
  Serial.println("Disconnected from Server");
  while(client.status()!=0){
    delay (10);
   }
  }
```

and this error comes up in the console:
[image]

even if I use the #include, still this pops out
[image]

Comment: The library you're currently using probably doesn't support ESP8266, try using https://github.com/nRF24/RF24. Just as a preemptive measure to avoid issues: 1. Make sure you decouple the 3.3V output - an 1000uF electrolytic capacitor `-` to GND and `+` to 3.3V. 2. Do not use ribbon cables, duponts should be okay, soldered is best. 3. When in high noise environment (electric motors etc.) also add a ceramic capacitor to the power rail.

Comment: The error is because you don't have that library on your computer.  Correct?

Comment: @Avamander I edited the post, still, doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JeanoDuhaylungsod Use *only* one of the libraries at once. Open `Examples`->`RF24`->`PingPair` and build on that.

Comment: You also have to make sure your ESP8266 core is up to date. Boards manager allows you to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is: .../packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/SPI/**src/SPI.h**:1:23: fatal error: SPI_Class.h: No such file or directory...

You have some wrong SPI library there. The original folder `packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/SPI` doesn't contain `src` subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it's possible to connect the two with TMRH20's RF24 library, which seems to be what you are using (judging by the name of the library). I'm currently building something with those very two components.

*Instead, the error is that **SPI_Class.h** can't be found by the IDE*. I can't recognize the name either, but if that is from attempting to include SPI to interface with the NRF24L01, you'd want **SPI.h** instead.

Comment: I also tried the #include<SPI.h.> but the same error still pops out

Comment: Was that after removing the SPI_Class library, or was it still present?
Also, have you tried with a fresh standalone non-admin install or with odd libraries removed/disabled?

Comment: the spi problem's fine now. but is there a way to get in touch with you? I want you're help with my project because you said you're working with similar hardware. If that's ok with you?

Comment: I'm glad that I or one of us could help, but I haven't actually gotten that far with this yet. I've gotten one of the test sketches that came with the library working, so I know it's possible, but I haven't done anything else yet. Aside from that, it's for a college project (and I have many other classes at the same time), so I need to devote my time to getting that working and I don't have much time to help with another.

Comment: I should mention that in my case, it still only works some fraction of the time and tends to crash on me; I think there's some place in the library that tends to hang when using an ESP8266. I'd love to hear about other peoples' experience; it could also be that my chips are counterfeits...

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Arduino IDE and the libraries that I need, it works fine now. It must be because someone used my laptop and installed some rfid libraries which caused some problems in the libraries folders.